# Javascript Best Practices - Sorting Mixed Data from Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I just started trying Javascript and I'm struggling. My end result is supposed to be a chronological timeline of activities (Calls, Meetings, Tasks).

I'm receiving a file from an application with different types of records. It contains Calls, Meetings, and Tasks. When I receive the file, they are in no particular order and each record type has different fields. I need to get them into the same table but sorted by date.
Here is a sample file with a Call and a Task but it might have 10 or more records of differing type.

```
[
{
    "Owner": {
        "name": "Raymond Carlson",
    },
    "Check_In_State": null,
    "Activity_Type": "Calls",
    "Call_Start_Time": "2022-10-23T20:00:00-05:00",
    "$editable": true,
    "Call_Agenda": "Need to call and discuss some upcoming events",
    "Subject": "Call scheduled with Florence"
},
{
    "Owner": {
        "name": "Raymond Carlson",
    },
    "Check_In_State": null,
    "Activity_Type": "Tasks",
    "Due_Date": "2022-10-24",
    "$editable": true,
    "Description": "-Review Action Items from Last week”,
    "Subject": "Complete Onboarding"
}
]
```

This is what I'm doing now and I know it's not the best way to go about it.

```
         for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
 
            var activityType0 = (obj[0].Activity_Type)
            var activityOwner0 = (obj[0].Owner.name);

            if (activityType0 == "Events") {
                start0 = (obj[0].Start_DateTime)
                startDate0 = new Date(start0);
                activityDate0 = startDate0.toLocaleString();
                activityTitle0 = (obj[0].Subject);
                activityDesc0 = (obj[0].Description);
            }
            else if (activityType0 == "Tasks"){
                dueDate0 = (obj[0].Due_Date)
                activityDate0 = dueDate0;
                activityTitle0 = (obj[0].Subject);
                activityDesc0 = (obj[0].Description);
            }
            else if (activityType0 == "Calls"){
                callStart0 = (obj[0].Call_Start_Time)
                callStartTime0 = new Date(callStart0);
                activityDate0 = callStartTime0.toLocaleString();
                activityTitle0 = (obj[0].Subject);
                activityDesc0 = (obj[0].Call_Agenda);
            }
    }
```

So regardless of the type of record, I have an
activityOwner,
activityDate,
activityTitle,
activityDesc,
And that's what I need.

Aside from that code above needing work, now my question is, what do I need to do with these values for each record to put them in order by "activityDate". Do I need to put them back into an array then sort and if so, what's the best approach?

Thank you much!

Comment: If you just want to sort by date, you can do something like `const getTimestamp = activity => new Date(activity.Start_DateTime ?? activity.Due_Date ?? activity.Call_Start_Time).valueOf()` and then `obj.sort((a, b) => getTimestamp(a) - getTimestamp(b))`. Or do you also want to normalize the data?

Comment: Use the map function to prepare the array of objects where the object's property will be what you want. Also here you can convert the date into a common format. Then use the sort function. You can get some idea regarding the sort function in this link. https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/javascript-array-sort-tutorial-how-to-use-js-sort-methods-with-code-examples/

Answer (score 0):

Right now I'm not really sure what your end goal is, is it sorting by activity type or activity date ?

If it's the latter, you can try referring to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123953/how-to-sort-an-object-array-by-date-property), or try to sort activity type by the ASCII number of each starting letter in each type (e.g. "C" in "Call", "T" in "Tasks", etc.)

Comment: Thanks Dennis. I think I put "by date" in the question somewhere (I'll edit and put "activityDate"). So based on your link, it sounds like I need to put them back into an array? I don't think there is a way to sort them from the original file since the dates are in different formats.