# Append record number to variable name when looping array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I'm brand new to javascript and appreciate everyone's help. I'm looping an array that might have 5 to 10 different records in it. This is what I'm doing so far and it works just fine. I didn't think including the array was necessary but let me know if it is.

```
obj = relatedActivities.data;
console.log(obj);

  for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
     var activityType = (obj[i].Activity_Type)
    }
```

The only problem with this is I need to put each record's value in a particular place.
What I want is a different variable every time it loops.

So the first record, the variable name would be something like:

**activityType0 = obj[0].Activity_Type**

and for the second record it would be:

**activityType1 = obj[1].Activity_Type**

I hope that makes sense.

Thank you all much!

Comment: Why not put the values in an array? Why do you feel that you need separate variables? That's not a typical thing to do in JavaScript.

Comment: What is the intended use for this? Is there a reason you can't just call the corresponding value in the current existing array? If your variables are `activityType0` and `activityType1` then somewhere you are referencing the **0** and **1** values to call those specific variables. Why not just use `relatedActivities.data[0].Activity_Type`? It may seem more efficient because the variable names are easier to read or shorter, but it is far less efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well |  maybe you hope so,This is basically the same answer as above | except that we avoid namespace pollution

```js
relatedActivities.data.forEach((o, i,arr) => {
   arr[i] = {}; 
   arr[i][`activityType${i}`] = o.activityType;  
})

relatedActivities.data.forEach(o => console.log(o))
```

Answer (score 1):

While I'm not sure there is any practical use for doing this, I will post this for the sake of answering the question.

Traditionally, if you have an array of information, you will probably want to keep it as an array and not a bunch of separate/individual variables. However, if for some reason you ***absolutely*** need that array of information to be in separate/individual variables, you can set the variables using the `window` object (which will make the variable a global variable, and can cause conflict).

```
relatedActivities.data.forEach((obj, i) => {
    window[`activityType${i}`] = obj.Activity_Type
});

console.log(activityType0);
console.log(activityType1);
```

Basically any global variable is typically called by its variable name, like `activityType0`. However, you can also call it through the window object like so: `window.activityType0` or `window["activityType0"]`. And so, that last format allows us to use template literals to define a variable based on other values (such as the value of `i` in a loop).

Comment: Thank you much. This was very helpful. I definitely need to get to the basics of Javascript and I will soon to learn best practices. 
The data for each record is mixed. I outlined it in more depth [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74176683/javascript-best-practices-sorting-mixed-data-from-array) in this post. The reason I was pulling the data into variables is because they need to be modified separately. 
But, I'll take the advice of using the information from the array and see what I can do. 
I appreciate it.